# Creating a range and reassign to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I build a range that I am trying to reassign from one sheet to another, but it fails with an error.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  thisWeek = 37;
  var firstWeek = [];
  var unprotectRange = [];
  firstWeek[0] = sourceSheet.getRange('E6:E12');
  firstWeek[1] = sourceSheet.getRange('F8:F10');

  const columnsPerWeek = 51;

  for (var k = thisWeek - 1; k < 53; k++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < firstWeek.length; l++) {
      if (
        sourceSheet
          .getRange(firstWeek[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek * k).getA1Notation())
          .isBlank()
      ) {
        unprotectRange.push(
          sourceSheet.getRange(
            firstWeek[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek * k).getA1Notation()
          )
        );
      }
    }
  }

  var range2 = destinationSheet.getRange(unprotectRange.getA1Notation());
  var protection = destinationSheet.protect().setDescription('Maintain');
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(range2);
}
```

Now I get the error: 'TypeError: unprotectRange.getA1Notation is not a function' at the statement

```
var range2 = destinationSheet.getRange(unprotectRange.getA1Notation());
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what ranges are unprotected? Are you just trying to unprotect range  that are blank? Also, `protection` is `undefined`.

Comment: I have X destinationSheets (which are protected) and I need to unprotect certain ranges in all destinationSheets.

Comment: Based on what criteria?

Comment: Each player in the team has his own sheet (destinationSheet), The array firstWeek contains all ranges (each range represents a game of the season). Those ranges in firstWeek which are empty (because for that game we dont yet have a full team) I want the players to be able to edit in their own sheet (basically entering yes/no/maybe).

Comment: `unprotectRange` is an array. You need to select an element within the array like `unprotectRange[0]`.

Comment: @Diego: is there a way in the loop to make `unprotectRange` not be an array, but instead a set of ranges so that I can perform this statement `protection.setUnprotectedRanges(range2);`?

Comment: First, what type of protection is it? There are two types : ``sheet`` and ``range``. In UI, you'll see protect sheet, "except" ranges. `except` is a keyword denoting `sheet` type of protection. Do show how you define `protection`

Comment: @mortpiedra [`protection.setUnprotectedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges) _expects_ an array. Why are you using `range2` to pull out a single range? You could simply call `protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectRange)`.

Comment: @TheMaster: I added the definition of `protection`

Comment: @Diego : as you surely notice I am a beginner at this, so I most likely do a lot of weird/wrong things. Thanks for your unbelievable input and patience. So `unprotectRange` is an array with ranges tied to sourceSheet, right? What I want to do is unprotect those ranges in the `destinationShee`t. Please note: there are many `destinationSheets`, so I do not want to loop through an array each time.

Comment: @mortpiedra As diego said, Does this work: `protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectRange)`?

Comment: @TheMaster I can only do this `const protection = sourceSheet.protect().setDescription('Maintain');
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectRange);` but what I need is this `const protection = destinationSheet.protect().setDescription('Maintain');
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectRange);`

Comment: @TheMaster When I try to run it with `destinationSheet` I get the error: 'The range must be part of the sheet'

Comment: @mortpiedra You only need to push a1notation strings. I updated my answer. Test and see

Comment: @Diego & TheMaster Ahhh man you guys are amazing! Thanks a lot! I struggle like crazy just to put the questions together and you guys come up with these solutions. Crazy good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `unprotectRange`  is a array of ranges from source sheet. They need to be strings(A1Notations). Push only the A1 notations.
- Convert the strings(A1notations) to ranges  of destination sheet using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`setProtectedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges) will then accept this array.

```
/*...*/
if (
  sourceSheet
    .getRange(firstWeek[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek * k).getA1Notation())
    .isBlank()
) {
  unprotectRange.push(
    firstWeek[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek * k).getA1Notation()/*Modified*/
  );
}
/*...*/
const ranges2 = unprotectRange.map(a1Notation => destinationSheet.getRange(a1Notation));
const protection = destinationSheet.protect().setDescription('Maintain');
protection.setUnprotectedRanges(ranges2);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately I get an error 'Range not found' at the statement `const ranges2 = unprotectRange.map(a1Notation => destinationSheet.getRange(a1Notation));`

Comment: @mortpiedra Log `unprotectRange` and see if `destinationSheet` has all the ranges in `unprotectRange`

Comment: uhu I am not sure what you mean.   In the loop I put  `Logger.log(sourceSheet.getRange(firstWeek[l].offset(0, columnsPerWeek *k ).getA1Notation()).getA1Notation());`  I got E6:E12
F8:F10
F6:F12
G8:G10
G6:G12
H8:H10

Comment: I also changed: `thisWeek = 1;  const columnsPerWeek = 1; for (var k = thisWeek-1; k < 3; k++)`

Comment: @mortpiedra `E6:E12 F8:F10 F6:F12 G8:G10 G6:G12 H8:H10` Are all these ranges available in destinationSheet?

Comment: Sorry I have tried to figure out what you mean with your question 'Are all these ranges available'? All the cells are available yes. The purpose of the script logic is to define these ranges, but that's is obviousto you. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: also the message: Range not found at [unknown function](Code:379:67) at test(Code:379:32)

Comment: @mortpiedra Are the ranges actual empty cells in destination sheet? If it's not, insert rows /columns as necessary. Also provide `console.log(JSON.stringify(unprotectRange))`

Comment: FYI: I have created 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2' for this test function and they are totally empty. I have reduced the logic ( `for (var k = thisWeek-1; k < 1; k++){` )   so that now I only get the ranges: E6:E12 and F8:F10. In the debugger I see that `unprotectRange` contains 2 records.  The JSON log you requested is: [{},{}]

Comment: Also: if you create the function test in a spreadsheet containing only the two sheets 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2' I assume you would get the same error. Or shall I post a public link to my spreadsheet?